# signalr with windows azure hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, signalr

I have been using **signalR** and I realized that you need .Net 4.5 to run it, but it seems as though Azure only allows .Net 4.0. Does anyone have any workarounds?  Or would I have to find a hosting that supports .net 4.5?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need .NET 4.5 to run SignalR it runs against .NET 4.0

Comment: My `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs()` keeps throwing an error and as soon as i upgrade to .net 4.5 it compiles

Comment: Knowing what error would be nice so I can help you fix it.

Comment: @dflower sorry, i forgot to include that, its ok i upgraded to 4.5 and got my azure deployment to start working after i upgraded the sdk.  Thanks again, david!

Answer (score 0):

Azure sdk is compatible with .net 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

.Net 4.5 is included in OS Family 3 (Windows Server 2012 image).  You can set this in your service definition file.